# 'As to why' vs. 'why'

Tags: grammar, phrase-meaning, phrase-usage

I have seen that some people use **as to why** instead of **why** in sentences such as bellow

> Michael was concerned **as to why** his address changed.

1- Is is grammatically correct to use **as to why** in the above sentence?

2- What would be the difference between **why** and **as to why**?

Comment: I found this https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/38141/meaning-and-correct-use-of-as-to-why but still need to hear more opinions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think there is much of a difference in regards to how these two phrases are used in everyday English conversation. However, [***as to something***](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/as+to), unlike ***why***, is actually a phrase on its own and somewhat similar to the expression [***as per***](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/as%20per), but probably not exactly the same. It can be used with anything you like. So, you could say:

> **As to** the matter at hand, we must act firmly and without delay.
>   **As to** why I was late today, I told him that I got stuck in a one-hour traffic jam on my way to work.

But let's now get back to your question. First of all, your sentence is correct. Secondly, I don't think that in your particular case here there would be any difference whether you use ***as to*** or not. But we could turn things around and rephrase my second example in such a way that there is no ***as to*** in it:

> In answer to the question **why** I was late today, I told him that I got stuck in a one-hour traffic jam on my way to work.

Just notice how the phrasing has changed compared to the original sentence. So, to sum things up, while ***why*** is simply an adverb, ***as to*** is always ***as to SOMETHING*** where ***something*** can be anything, including ***why***.

Answer (score 2):

The subordinate clause "why his address changed" is a content clause.  It's substantive.  It works well as a subject or an object, but it doesn't work well as an adjunct.

In formal or scholastic English, the following two sentences fail for the same reason:

> Michael was concerned John.
>   Michael was concerned why his address changed.

The substantives at the ends of these sentences are simply lying there, unattached to anything.  They're not subjects.  They're not objects.  They're not sensible.  However, we can change that.  We can add something that creates a relationship.

Prepositions work quite well:

> Michael was concerned *about* John.
>   Michael was concerned *as to* why his address changed.

Participles also work:

> Michael was concerned *considering* John.
>   Michael was concerned *regarding* why his address changed.